# Add "id" to the first in each object in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, frontend, javascript-objects

I could add **"id"** to each object in the array **"data"**:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: 24 },
  { name: "Marry", age: 18 },
  { name: "Tom", age: 15 },
]

for(const key in data) {
  data[key]['id'] = key;
}

console.log(data);
```

But **"id"** is added to the last in each object in the array **"data"**:

```js
[
  { name: "John", age: 24, id: "0" },
  { name: "Marry", age: 18, id: "1" },
  { name: "Tom", age: 15, id: "2" }
]
```

My desired result is this below adding **"id"** to the first in each object in the array **"data"**:

```js
[
  { id: "0", name: "John", age: 24 },
  { id: "1", name: 'Marry', age: 18 },
  { id: "2", name: 'Tom', age: 15 }
]
```

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create the array **"newData"** with **"id"** and the array **"data"**:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: 24 },
  { name: "Marry", age: 18 },
  { name: "Tom", age: 15 },
]

const newData = [];

for(const key in data) {

  const obj = {
    id: key,
    ...data[key]
  }

  newData.push(obj);
}

console.log(newData);
```

This is the result:

```js
[
  { id: "0", name: "John", age: 24 },
  { id: "1", name: 'Marry', age: 18 },
  { id: "2", name: 'Tom', age: 15 }
]
```

In addition, if you want **"id"** of **Number** type, use **"Number()"**:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", age: 24 },
  { name: "Marry", age: 18 },
  { name: "Tom", age: 15 },
]

const newData = [];

for(const key in data) {

  const obj = {
    id: Number(key), // Here
    ...data[key]
  }

  newData.push(obj);
}

console.log(newData);
```

This is the result:

```js
[
  { id: 0, name: "John", age: 24 },
  { id: 1, name: 'Marry', age: 18 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 15 }
]
```